# Non-collapsing but still (line-)breakable space in HTML?

Tags: html, whitespace

What can I use in HTML if I want to have whitespace in the middle of the line that looks like three spaces, but can still be broken if the line gets too long?

Regular whitespace gets collapsed (a run of spaces looks the same as a single space), and at the non-breaking space (&nbsp) the line cannot be broken.

**Update**: I think what I really want is a ＜pre＞ tag that can still break long lines (I need to display source code).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about one or more em spaces (&emsp;)? Granted, this would depend on what the user's font size is. If that doesn't really work in your design, consider an en space (&ensp;).

You might also want to look at [this table of various spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Table_of_spaces) on Wikipedia.

Comment: In *theory*, all these should be collapsed to regular spaces by a conforming agent (HA!).

Comment: If the spec wants them collapsed, what good are they? But fortunately, it seems that browsers do not follow that part of the spec.

Comment: I just hope that everyone has the fonts for that.

Comment: Actually this should work. The definition of “white space” in HTML deliberately excludes U+2002 EM SPACE. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1

Comment: Interesting... although: "This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters."

Comment: @Simon, right, the behavior is undefined in that section, so default behavior would be followed: the characters would be printed without collapse.

Answer (score 24):

I actually have the exact answer you’re looking for.  I searched everywhere for this answer and nothing anyone suggested worked perfectly.  So, I thought up a solution and tried it and was floored that it worked without any flaw!

[Garrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605470/578288) was actually right (he just didn’t explain it or take it all the way).  The solution is instead of putting `&nbsp;` alone, put `&nbsp;<wbr>`.  Just do a simple search and replace and add the `<wbr>` tag after every `&nbsp;`.  Works perfectly!

The `<wbr>` tag is a little-known tag supported in all major browsers that tells the browser to put a newline here ONLY if it is needed.

Update:  I found one browser that this doesn’t work exactly right in – IE 8!  They actually took out the `<wbr>` tag!  I solved this issue by creating a class that says:

```css
.wbr:before { content: "\200B" }
```

and instead of replacing `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp;<wbr>`, replace it with the following:

```html
&nbsp;<wbr><span class='wbr'></span>
```

In PHP, this would look like:

```php
$text = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;<wbr><span class='wbr'></span>", $text);
```

Don’t forget to add the class as well.

Obviously this is getting quite a bit excessive, replacing a single space with all of that, but it does work just as desired and since I never saw the markup it worked for me.

If this is too messy, another solution is to exchange double spaces for a `&nbsp;` followed by a normal space.  This will alternate `&nbsp;` and normal spaces and works in my tests.

In PHP, this would look like:

```php
$text = str_replace("  ","&nbsp; ", $text);
```

Hope this helps!  I put enough research into this; I thought I should pass it on.

Comment: Awesome answer. Learned about `<wbr>` today

Answer (score 5):

Won't a space between two non-breaking spaces work?

**&nbsp; &nbsp;**

Comment: heh this is a great answer. It works perfectly. I had to do this for an email template solution. Worked out well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're [not targeting IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) (except 8, standards mode):

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap">   </span>
```

For IE, `<span style="width:3ex"></span>` works in quirks mode, so merge them and...

```
<span style="width:3ex;white-space:pre-wrap">   </span>
```

which seems to work everywhere I tried... except IE7 standards. D'oh!

Comment: Well, there will be IE8. And in say, four years from now, our corporate clients will have updated...

Comment: please put the link with the browser support page back, that was neat

Answer (score 3):

How about [<wbr>](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)?

Answer (score 2):

How about two `&nbsp;`'s followed by a regular space? The only disadvantage to that (as far as I know) is that if a line break does naturally fall at the regular space, you'll have a bit of trailing space on the preceding line due to the non-breaking spaces, but I don't think that would ever make a difference in the actual appearance of the page.

Comment: It would, if that bit of length makes the difference between the first of the 2 words appearing on the end of that line, or the start of the next, since you still pad a non-breaking space to the end of it, making it "longer" to the splitting mechanism. Also, even if it doesn't, and it breaks between them, the word on the next line would start with a space, which should also not happen.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to take a step back and ask what it is you're trying to render. What does this extra-wide space signify?

Comment: I want a PRE tag that preserves the original indentation (but still wraps long lines)

Answer (score -1):

it give's 100px  to the left space between your text 
 spaces example

span style="margin-left:100px;"

(n_n)